# 2D array of objects and JButtons

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, jbutton

I have a question about "linking" a 2D array of a class to JButttons. I'm having a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024362/2d-array-and-jbutton) previously-asked question and found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13024499/14585560) to be very helpful. I need to create a 4x4 board of JButtons with pictures. I'm using a Square class to represent each of the grid squares and they should each be JButtons. I initialised it in my Board class through `private Square[][] square = new Square[4][4];`

However, I don't understand how to add an image to a JButton when the class is different. I originally did it by `square[i][j] = new JButton(p);` where p is the object name of the image I'm using but it throws an error: "JButton cannot be converted to Square".

How would I go about avoiding this error? Also, I don't want to create a 2D array of JButtons.

My Square class is basically:

```
public class Square extends JButton
{
    private int xNum;
    private int yNum;
        
    public Square(int xNum, int yNum) {
        this.xNum = xNum;
        this.yNum = yNum;
    }

    // and then a few get and set methods...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see the code for you object square but im assuming that you can just add a private variable JButton into your square class, you can then create getters and setters.  Now when you loop through your for loop and initialize your squares, you can do

```
square[i][j] = new square();
square[i][j].setJButton(new JButton(p));
```

and whenever you need to access the JButton call

```
square[i][j].getJButton();
```

Hope this helps, if I understood your question wrong please comment and I will try to get back to you quickly.

Comment: Also when initializing objects you cant initialize it to be another object unless the other object is a sub part of it.  There's a whole entire topic on it called polymorphism, it is very useful in bigger projects and if you continue with Java you are bound to run into a situation where you need it.  In your case I really don't think you will need to use this technique.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If I've extended the Square class to JButton, would I still have to add the private variable of JButton?

Comment: I've also given the original code for my square class, and I think I've shown the code for my square object in the post. I tried your solution but I get the error "cannot find symbol in `square[i][j].setJButton(new JButton(p));` "...

Comment: So instead of extending JButton, id recommend for what you need, underneath your private int xNum and yNum add private JButton jb;
Then you have your getters and setters for jb(or whatever you named it) and then it should work fine.