# Removing anonymous listener

Tags: java, collections, listener, anonymous

When trying to adopt the style of implementing a listener using anonymous or nested class in order to hide the notification methods for other uses than listening (i.e. I don't want anybody to be able to call actionPerformed). For example from [java action listener: implements vs anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631641/java-action-listener-implements-vs-anonymous-class?lq=1):

```
public MyClass() {
    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //doSomething
        }
    });
}
```

The question is if theres an elegant way to remove the listener again using this idiom? I figured out that the instantiation of `ActionListener` does not produce equal objects every time so `Collection.remove()` won't remove the originally added object.

In order to be considered equal the listeners should have the same outer this. To implement equals I would need to get hold of outer this for the other object. So it will go something like this (which I find a little bit clumpsy):

```
interface MyListener {
    Object getOuter();
}

abstract class MyActionListener extends ActionListener
    implement MyListener {
}

public MyClass() {
    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // doSomething on MyClass.this
        }
        public Object getOuter() {
           return MyClass.this;
        }
        public boolean equals(Object other)
        {
           if( other instanceof MyListener )
           {
              return getOuter() == other.getOuter();
           }
           return super.equals(other);
        });
    }
 }
```

Or will I be forced to keep the ActionListener object as a (private) member of the outer class?

Comment: You can make those objects equal by overriding `equals()` in anonymous class, no?

Comment: Why can't you use removeActionListener?

Comment: removeActionListener depends on the object being removed compares equal with the object being supplied to removeActionListener. I've edited the question with explaination why I think implementing equals() will imply some overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign your anonymous listener to a private local variable, e.g.

```
public MyClass() {
    private Button myButton = new Button();
    private ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //doSomething
        }
    };
    private initialize() {
        myButton.addActionListener(actionListener);
    }
}
```

Later you can use the private variable `actionListener` to remove it again.

Comment: Although this is not the answer I wished for, but it looks that one need to resort to assign the listener to a local variable.

Answer (score 4):

Well that's the beauty of anonymous classes - they're anonymous :-)

No, there's no similarly elegant idiom to remove the listener again. The only way is to iterate through `getActionListeners()` and remove the one you want. Of course, if there is only one it's as easy as:

```
myButton.removeActionListener( myButton.getActionListeners()[ 0 ] );
```

which is not too ugly.